# JAX-WS MTOM delete attachment after sending to client

Tags: java, jax-ws, attachment, mtom

I am using the reference implementation of JAX-WS with Java 1.6.  On my server I have Web Service method which returns a response with an attachment as a javax.activation.DataHandler.

```
File myFile = new File("tempFile.txt"); //existing temp file to send back
DataHandler dh = new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(myFile));
//cant delete myFile yet, but end of web service method
```

What I need to do is **delete the file after it has been completely sent** from the server to the client. However my webservice method has finished before the response is sent from the client.

What can I do to mark the file for deletion, or is there a callback I can hook into to delete the file after transmission?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some answers to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158568/tomcat-6-how-to-delete-temporary-files-after-a-web-method-call-has-ended).